# Internet not working after removing hotspot shield plugin

Tags: hotspot-shield

I have Baidu anti virus installed in my computer as well as hotspot shield.

The problem started when Baidu suggested that I remove some plugins including hotspot shield.

After removing the plugins the internet stopped working on my computer only, other devices can connect to the WIFI without problem.

I tried to reinstall hotspot shield to fix the problem but now hotspot shield doesn't work and keep saying there is an internal error, clicking on the button "fix it now" does nothing.

I tried to check the LAN setting and that didn't help at all.

Tried to do recovery for my computer and it always fail for unknown reason.

Should I format my computer or is there any other way to fix the problem?

Comment: At the very least some details regarding OS version etc. would help.

Comment: I had a similar problem.  I opened the hood of my car the other day, did some stuff, and now it won't start.  How do I fix it, or do I need to rebuild the transmission?

Comment: I am sorry as this is the first time I ask about something regard my computer so I don't know the requirement needed to fix a problem.                               Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry Pro            2013 Microsoft Corporation.                 System                                       Processor: Intel (R) Core (TM) i3 CPU        M 380 @ 2.53GHz 2.53GHz                     Installed memory : 3.00 GB.              System type : 6-5 it Operation System, ×6 4 - based processor.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

1. Resetting your network adapter
2. Removing any custom proxy settings that were automatically set by HotSpot Shield

---

**1. Resetting your network adapter:**

Netsh commands for resetting your network adapter in Windows 8

The following is a list of the Netsh commands you can use at a Command Prompt with administrator privileges to reset your network adapter in Windows 8.

```
netsh advfirewall reset
```

Restores the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security policy to the default policy. The current active policy can be optionally exported to a specified file. In a Group Policy object, this command returns all settings to not configured and deletes all connection security and firewall rules.

```
netsh branchcache reset
```

Resets the BranchCache service. Flushes the local cache. Every configuration parameter of BranchCache will be reset to its default value.

```
netsh int ip reset
```

Resets TCP/IP and related components to a clean state.

```
netsh int ipv6 reset
```

Resets IPv6 configuration state.

```
netsh winsock reset
```

Resets Winsock Catalog to a clean state. All Winsock Layered Service Providers which were previously installed must be reinstalled. This command does not affect Winsock Name Space Provider entries.

Reference: [Resetting your network adapter in Windows 8](http://www.geeksinphoenix.com/blog/post/2012/09/16/Resetting-your-network-adapter-in-Windows-8.aspx)

---

**2. Removing any custom proxy settings that were automatically set by HotSpot Shield**

Based on the type of browser you are using, do the following to make sure there are no **proxy settings** on the browser:

If you are using **Internet Explorer** go to:

- `Tools` -> `Internet Options` -> `Connections` Tab -> `LAN settings`
- Make sure none of the check boxes are selected on this screen

If you are using **Chrome** go to:

- Chrome menu -> `Settings` -> `Show Advanced Settings...` -> `Change Proxy Settings...` -> LAN Settings'
- Make sure none of the check boxes are selected on this screen

Note: This will change the Internet Explorer setting which is the same setting used by Chrome.

If you are using **Firefox** go to:

- `Tools` -> `Options` > `Advanced` -> `Network` tab -> `Settings...` in the `Connection` section -> select `No Proxy` OR select `Use system proxy settings` if the Internet Explorer settings were changed as mentioned above.

Please see [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5hD8NV7Aek) for the same.

Comment: I have tried this but it didn't change anything. I cannot access the Internet by using any browser. However I have Hamachi installed and it's somehow able to connect

Comment: You may also try the steps in the link below to try to rest your network adaptor: http://www.geeksinphoenix.com/blog/post/2012/09/16/Resetting-your-network-adapter-in-Windows-8.aspx

Comment: After using the netsh winsock reset everything started working fine

Comment: Awesome. Glad to know it helped. Have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you tried all of the options and still have the same problem, go to network and sharing center in the control panel and click on change adapter setting. There is a list with many installed drivers and protocols. Look for "hotspot shield routing driver 6" or something along those lines. Then click uninstall. Check if you can access any websites now.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the problem with it. I couldn't surf the Internet without Hotspot Shield, which sucked. But luckily someone in another website told me what to do. If you ever have the same problem, here's how to fix it:

1. Start >> Control Panel >> Network and Internet >> Network and Sharing Center
2. On the side there is a 'Change Adapter Settings' click on it.
3. Right-Click your adapter. NOTE: Make sure it is your adapter and not Wi-Fi! In this case my adapter is Hamachi. So Right-Click >> Status >> Properties
4. Now if you are using Hotspot Shield, you should see 'Hotspot Shield Routing Driver 6' or something along those lines. Disable it by unticking and then Select it. (**MAKE SURE ITS SELECTED! THE WRITING SHOULD BE HIGHLIGHTED WITH BLUE!**) And then press 'Uninstall'.
5. Now reconnect with your Wi-Fi and that should fix the problem. Hopefully :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the settings for proxies were fine(Automatic). When I checked the network settings, it had the Hotspot 'special' Protocol enabled.
(That means, hotspot works overriding our own Internet Protocols IPv4 or IPv6)
 I uninstalled it, internet came back running to me like a *'dog waiting for it's master'* ;)
Guys, try it out once and let me know if it works.

Note: If you don't know how to reach your IP proxy settings, follow:
Right click your wifi notification icon in the right corner-> Open Network and Sharing Centre->Change Adapter Settings(in the left corner)->And then, to Uninstall, select the Hotspot Protocol and hit on the Uninstall button below the Listbox.

P.S:If you are so keen to have a hotspot of your own, create your own hotspot with your Internet Protocols.
[Create a Wifi hotspot](https://sanjutalks.wordpress.com/2012/08/03/creating-a-wifi-hotspot-in-windows-7-sharing-internet-connection-for-use-in-android/)

Answer (score -1):

wenn none of these solution solve the problem:

uninstall your software und reinstall it. HSS corrupts your connction & u can never access to.

ps: discoverd the soluttion today after 5 hours searching and trying different ways.

Comment: This seems to be very vague and generic advice. What does it even mean for software to "corrupt your connection"? Also, even though it's only three lines, your answer is very hard to read. Please avoid textspeak and use a spell checker.