# No internet with Windows 10

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, internet, internet-connection

Today my internet stopped working today on my Acer Laptop with windows 10 pro 64bit.
My wifi shows that it is connected to my home network but there is no internet. If i run ipconfig, i don't see my wifi (or ethernet) adaptor in the list.
I have also tried to connect using an ethernet cable with wifi disabled, does not work.

I have tried to download the latest drivers manually from Acer's website and it too does not work.

I have tried many restarts and i've looked at the other stack exchange answers but they didn't work for me.
I don't have any anti-virus installed, only windows defender. So i don't think it's an anti-virus issue
I think it might be an update that ocurred this morning. But i tried uninstalling all updates for today, but that didn't work either.

Any other advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Right click on the wifi icon and select troubleshoot problems,it will reset the adapter and I think then you can access internet.

Comment: tried that, didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused when I uninstalled Hotspot Shield.
The solution was found in this SO question https://superuser.com/a/978439/362589